# Why is Silverlight chart binding occasionally not updating data?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've got ten bar series in a chart from the Silverlight toolkit. Every 15 seconds the data they are linked to is updated. Occasionally one of bars does not move when its value changes. It may fix itself on the next refresh 15 seconds later. Five textblocks bound to the same data do update.